# Binary Search tree deletion optimization

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, tree

I have just started implementing Binary Search tree on my own without using any tutorials online.
Please have a look and suggest how can I make code less cluttered and more faster. Right now I am using lots of if-else conditions and want to remove them as much as I can.

```
boolean deleteNode(int data, TreeNode node )
{
    if( data < node.key) deleteNode(data, node.left);
    else if( data > node.key) deleteNode(data, node.right);

    else {
        System.out.println("Value of node = " + node.key);
        //case 1 - Left and Right is null - Leaves
        if(node.left == null && node.right == null)
        { 
            if(node == node.parent.left)node.parent.left =  null;
            else node.parent.right = null;
            System.out.println("Inside first if");
        }

        //case 2 - One child is null

        else if(node.left !=null && node.right ==null)

        {
            if(node == node.parent.left)node.parent.left = node.left;
            else node.parent.right = node.left;

        }
        else if(node.right !=null && node.left ==null)
        {
            if(node == node.parent.right)node.parent.right = node.right;
            else node.parent.left = node.right;             
        }

        //case 3 - Delete node is an internal node

        else if(node.left !=null && node.right !=null)
        {
            TreeNode minNode = treeMin(node.right);

            if(minNode.parent == node)
            {
                if(node.parent == null)
                    {
                        node.key = minNode.key;
                        node.right = minNode.right;
                    }
                else{
                if(node == node.parent.left)
                    {
                        node.parent.left.key = minNode.key;
                        node.parent.right.right = minNode.right;

                    }
                if(node == node.parent.right)
                    {
                        node.parent.right.key = minNode.key;
                        node.parent.right.right = minNode.right;
                    }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if(node == node.parent.left)
                {
                    node.parent.left.key = minNode.key;
                    node.left.right = minNode.right;

                }
                else if(node == node.parent.right)
                {

                    node.parent.right.key = minNode.key;
                    node.right.left = minNode.right;

                }
            }
        }


    }
    return true;


}
```

Comment: These carry handling. Try to use `switch` statements to make it more readable.

Comment: There is no such thing as an `if` "loop".

Comment: Yeah I wrote it by mistake. Can you have a look at my code?

Comment: `left.key = minNode.key;
                        node.parent.right.right = minNode.right;` is probably erroneous as well as dispensable: in effect, all three cases with `node->right == minNode` (`minNode.parent == node`) are identical: just use the first notation. (`(node->right == minNode) == (null == node->right->left)`) `null == minNode->left` does _not_ mean that you need to keep `minNode` and `minNode->right`, only: in the `minNode.parent != node` branch, there's at least `node->right`, which may or may not be `minNode.parent`, and possibly quite a lot more, and both handlings look wrong.

Comment: `deleteNode()` looks very similar to AnkitSablok's question re. [Dictionary implemented using a Binary Search Tree](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/112082/93149) - is there a text book/other reference it would be of advantage for readers of both questions to know?

Answer (score 2):

You are always returning `true` so I guess you don't really need current return value. In that case you might want to try a bit different approach.
You want to do something like:

```
 if( data < node.key) {
    node.left = deleteNode(data, node.left);
 } else if( data > node.key) {
    node.right = deleteNode(data, node.right);
 } else {
    //here return resulting node after deletion, null if node had no children
 }
```

That way you don't need to know anything about parent

Answer (score 0):

I think that user158037's observation about the value you returned is directly related to a glaring omission:
The code is not documented. In particular, it doesn't say what `deleteNode(int data, TreeNode node)` is to accomplish (e.g., when `null == node`), or return.
Don't be afraid to provide too much context: the snippet contains little clue whether it is a member of `TreeNode` (tried that: got unwieldy for lack of *use this node instead*).

Postpone *faster* until you are comfortable with your *model of tree and node* and the way your code implements it - *and* you have *specific cause* to worry about run time.

The code below picks up user158037's suggestion to return the new root:

```
 /** delete {@code data} from binary search tree
  *  rooted at {@code node}, if present
  * @return root after deletion */
 // could be static but for override
    TreeNode deleteNode(int data, TreeNode node)
    {
        if (null == node)
            return null;
        if (data != node.key) {
            if (data < node.key)
                node.left = deleteNode(data, node.left);
            else // (data > node.key)
                node.right = deleteNode(data, node.right);
            return node;
        }

//      System.out.println("Value of node = " + node.key);
        if (null == node.left) {
            if (null == node.right) {
            // case 1 - Left and Right is null - Leaves
//              System.out.println("left and right null");
            } else {
            // case 2 - node has one child
            }
            return node.right;
        }
        TreeNode parent = node.right;
        if (parent == null) {
        // case 2 - node has one child
            return node.left;
        }
    // case 3 - node is an internal node
        TreeNode child = parent.left;
        if (null == child) {
        // almost simple: node.right is the leftmost node in its tree
            node.right = parent.right;
        } else {
            TreeNode grand = parent = node.left;
            if (null == parent.right) {
            // symmetrical: node.left is rightmost in its tree
                node.left = parent.left;
            } else {
            // find rightmost descendant to the left
                while (null != (child = parent.right)) {
                    grand = parent;
                    parent = child;
                }
            // replace rightmost descendant to the left
            //  by its left subtree ...
                grand.right = parent.left;
            }
        }
    // ... and replace node's key by that
    //  of its "most easily found" closest descendant 
        node.key = parent.key;
        return node;
    }
```

(*If* you use tracing: use a package, and consider tracing *run-time comments*.)
If `node` needs to be replaced, this manipulates the key instead, just like the code in the question. *The right thing to do* would be to replace `node` by one of its neighbours (`parent` in the snippet presented), requiring more reference manipulation.
(Don't do as I do: do as I say ;-)
I find it difficult to "return more than one value" from a Java function member - a natural with [PostScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) - contributing to the difficulty to specify&code a useful *node delete* in a class of a basic tree implementation.